# Visual Studio installer hanging when trying to install new features

Tags: visual-studio, installation

[image]

Does anyone else experience this issue?

The Visual Studio Installer gets to this point, but won't go any further.

It's fine if i run the installer separately, but if i want to install more .Net versions for example, i HAVE to go through Visual Studio to select them, in which case i get to this dialogue and it just won't work.
-I've tried elevating my permissions.
-Running as Admin.
Neither of which have worked.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

-I've tried elevating my permissions.
-Running as Admin.

Edit, just to clarify, it's not limited to .Net installs, it's anything from the following screen:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can check this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-update-visual-studio-installer/10162033). You can use vpn and try again.

Comment: What is the .net version you want to install via visual studio?

Comment: I'ts not limited to .net version. Have updated my description

Comment: Maybe you can report this on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report).